# Who scores in 0 outs, bases loaded, missed base at 2nd, on a deep foul fly in right field tag

Tags: baseball, officiating

0 outs, B4 hits deep fly to right catches but everyone is wheeling (and they drop relay ball is rolling around), R3 tags on third and scores, 2 misses third and scores, R1 behind him scores, BR obviously is out. Appeal is on R2 missing third.
Which runs score?
Only R1 (preceeding) not following (R3 who was forced?)

I think following runner scores, and preceding runners do not, but see reference.

http://www.umpirebible.com/ubBlog/archives/304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, preceding runners are only affected by an appeal play if both of two conditions occur:

- The appeal play is for a force out
- The appeal play is the third out of the inning

(I think this is mentioned pretty well in the Exception(3) section of the page you linked).  But neither of these apply to your question.

- There are zero outs at the start of the play, so the appeal is only the second out (with the initial catch being the first).  With less than 3 outs, force plays don't affect the scoring of runners crossing the plate.
- The first catch means the batter is out.  So there are no force plays anywhere from this point forward.  All plays are timed.  Scoring would depend on when runners cross the plate relative to when the third out is made.

Both R1 and R3 score.  B4 is out #1, R2 is out #2.  There are 2 outs.

Comment: now lets add one twist, instead of catching its a inside the park triple. now what

Comment: I don't see that makes much difference.  There's still not 3 outs, so appeals only affect that runner, not any others.

Comment: per the link above, it says no FOLLOWING runners can score

Comment: It says "no runs score" after saying that following runners not scoring is mentioned elsewhere.  That to me says that it's extended to preceding runners as well.

Comment: the wording is just bad following means runs ahead of the foul, and preceding means before the runner that had the foul both which happen in the scenario which made me ask this question.  I just broke the flowchart diagram